# Upload recorded file to AWS S3 storage or google drive

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, amazon-s3, wear-os

I have created an app to record the audio in the android wear but I am not able to transfer that recorded file to mobile phone as there is no dedicated file manager in Samsung galaxy watch 4. So for that I need to upload the the recorded file to the AWS S3 STORAGE.
Here is the code for audio recording.

```
package com.example.watch

import android.Manifest.permission
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.*
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Chronometer
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.amplifyframework.core.Amplify
import com.amplifyframework.storage.StorageException
import com.amplifyframework.storage.result.StorageUploadFileResult
import com.example.watch.databinding.ActivityMicrophoneBinding
import java.io.BufferedWriter
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileWriter
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*


@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class Microphone : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Initializing all variables..
    private var Stop: Button? = null
    private var Start: Button? = null
    private var statusTV:TextView? = null
    private var Chronometer:TextView?=null
    var fileName: String? = null
    var audioRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null
    var audiouri: Uri? = null
    var file: ParcelFileDescriptor? = null
    lateinit var status:TextView
    private var binding: ActivityMicrophoneBinding? = null
    private lateinit var chronometer: Chronometer
    private var audioFile: File? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_microphone)

        if (!CheckPermissions())
            RequestPermissions()
        AmplifyInit().intializeAmplify(this@Microphone)


        this.window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
        )
        supportActionBar!!.hide()
        // initialize all variables with their layout items.
        Start=binding!!.accelerometerStartButton
        Stop=binding!!.accelerometerStopButton
        status=binding!!.Status
        chronometer=binding!!.chronometer



        Start!!.setOnClickListener { // start recording method will
            // start the recording of audio.
            startRecording()

            Start!!.isEnabled=false
            status.text="Recording..."
            chronometer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            chronometer.start()

         startService()
        }
        Stop!!.setOnClickListener { // pause Recording method will
            // pause the recording of audio.
            pauseRecording()
            Start!!.isEnabled=true
            status.text="Recording Stopped"
            chronometer.stop()
            uploadFile()
            stopService()
        }

    }

    private fun startRecording() {


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
            val values = ContentValues(4)
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, fileName)
            values.put(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(Date())
            )

            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Music/Recordings/")

            audiouri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
            file = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(audiouri!!, "w")

            if (file != null) {
                audioRecorder = MediaRecorder()
                audioRecorder!!.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
                audioRecorder!!.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
                audioRecorder!!.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
                audioRecorder!!.setOutputFile(file!!.fileDescriptor)
                audioRecorder!!.setAudioChannels(1)
                audioRecorder!!.prepare()
                audioRecorder!!.start()
                audioRecorder!!.setOutputFile(getAudioFile().absolutePath)


            }
        }

        else {
            RequestPermissions()
        }


    }
    private fun getAudioFile(): File {
        if (audioFile == null) {
            audioFile = File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "Music/Recordings/")
        }
        return audioFile!!
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray,
    ) {

        // this method is called when user will
        // grant the permission for audio recording.
        when (requestCode) {

            REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val permissionToRecord = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    val permissionToStore = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    if (permissionToRecord && permissionToStore) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun CheckPermissions(): Boolean {
        // this method is used to check permission
        val result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        val result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun RequestPermissions() {
        // this method is used to request the
        // permission for audio recording and storage.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            arrayOf(permission.RECORD_AUDIO, permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE
        )
    }

    private fun pauseRecording() {
        Start!!.isEnabled=true
        stopService(Intent(this, ForegroundService::class.java))
        // below method will stop
        // the audio recording.
        try {
            audioRecorder!!.stop()
        } catch (stopException: RuntimeException) {
            // handle cleanup here
        }


    }
    fun startService() {
        val serviceIntent = Intent(this, ForegroundService::class.java)
        serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", "Foreground Service Example in Android")
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent)
    }

    fun stopService() {
        val serviceIntent = Intent(this, ForegroundService::class.java)
        stopService(serviceIntent)
    }

    companion object {
        // string variable is created for storing a file name
        private var mFileName: String? = null
        var permissionAccepted = false
        var permissions = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        // constant for storing audio permission
        const val REQUEST_AUDIO_PERMISSION_CODE = 1000
    }
    private fun uploadFile() {

        Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
            "Audio/audio.mp3",
            getAudioFile(),
            { result: StorageUploadFileResult ->
                Log.i(
                    "MyAmplifyApp",
                    "Successfully uploaded: " + result.key
                )
                Toast.makeText(this, "File has Successfully Uploaded:" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        ) { storageFailure: StorageException? ->
            Log.e(
                "MyAmplifyApp",
                "Upload failed",
                storageFailure
            )
            Toast.makeText(this, "Upload failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Now how can i modify my uploadfile function to upload the fiole to AWS S3, As i am getting this error.

```
E/amplify:aws-s3-storage:SinglePartUploadWorker: SinglePartUploadWorker failed with exception: kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Parent job is Cancelling; job=JobImpl{Cancelled}@9b17179
I/WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result RETRY for Work [ id=48cd3651-35e2-456e-9329-81930f5277a5, tags={ UPLOAD, awsS3StoragePlugin, 9, com.amplifyframework.storage.s3.transfer.worker.RouterWorker } ]
```

I am using dependecies:

```
 implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-api:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-datastore:2.1.0'
 implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-storage-s3:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:2.1.0'
```

Library:

```
  <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />
```

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75306664/edit) your post to include which library and version you are using.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I am using same method to upload JSON format file and in that case this is working but while uploading Mp3 file this is showing error.